# generate a random string with only certain characters allowed to repeat in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, random

Okay, I'm trying to generate a 10 character string containing specific characters.
With the conditions being, the letters can NOT be repeats (but the numbers CAN), and the string can ONLY contain a total of TWO letters, no more, no less. The final string output MUST be 8 numbers, and 2 letters.

```
numbers = ["1", "2", "3"]
letters = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
```

i.e. the string output should be similar to

```
123X21Y213
```

The problem is, I don't know how to do this, elegantly.
I did create a solution, but it was way too many lines, and it involved constantly checking the previous character of the string.
I'm really bad at this, and need something simpler.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have working code that you think could be improved, see http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
numbers = ["1", "2", "3"]
letters = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

from random import sample, shuffle


samp = sample(letters,2)+sample(numbers*3,8)
shuffle(samp)

print("".join(samp))
113332X2Z2
```

Or use choice and range:

```
from random import sample, shuffle,choice

samp = sample(letters,2)+[choice(numbers) for _ in range(8)]
shuffle(samp)

print("".join(samp))
1212ZX1131
```

Comment: How about `numbers*8`? As-is, the string `111111111XY` cannot be generated (whereas it seems to be acceptable).

Comment: @ThomasOrozco, I added choice, that will allow 111111111XY.